# localNotification.soundName

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

`localNotification.soundName` doesn't support sound with duration more than 30 second 
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,just sound with duration less than 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a notification. The user can't change the sound and it's annoying way before 30 seconds anyway.